# Does As2 compiler has limitations on number of lines of code?

Tags: compiler-construction, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

I writing a AS2 code to develop a certain application.

when my code exceeds 2352 lines, the swf doesnt compile, also it does not give me any error. I have checked for any syntax errors, but there are none.

Is there a specific limitation on number of lines to be written for as2 compiler?
Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I don't think so. To be sure, I wrote a script to generate some random AS2 code (makes random variables, random loops, if statements, methods + calls, objects, and trace statements). The result was an .as file that was over 13,000 lines long which ran with no problems under AS2 inside the flash cs5 ide.